# Как определить скорость интернет-соединения? (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью JS определить скорость интернета?

(Я попробовал способ следующий, но он иногда рассчитывает некорректно: ,засекаю текущее время (t1), беру картинку, загружаю ее,затем опять смотрю время (t2), высчитываю разницу (t2-t1) ну и дальше высчитываю скорость в кбит/с)

Comment: может показывать скорость некорректно, так как картинка кешируется.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь - с помощью js **никак** нельзя это сделать

Comment: Что бы кеширование убрать, можете запрашивать картинку с каким-нить `GET` параметром, а так, ваш метод рабочий на столько, на сколько это возможно для `js`

Comment: @KoVadim Я делаю "антикэш". Каждый раз при загрузке делаю: 
"?n=" + new Date()).getTime();

Comment: я бы открыл бы консольку браузера и посмотрел, как браузер смотрит на Ваш антикеш.

Comment: @Grundy beta.speedtest.net похоже исплользует вебсокеты + html5.

Comment: @KoVadim, что-то он у меня не очень открывается :) но на сколько я знаю, раньше они флэш использовали

Comment: Он может не открываться, если у Вас есть флеш. Это они экспериментируют:)

Comment: надо не картинку загружать, а что-то боле весомое, тогда минимум погрешностей имхо будет.

Comment: @Jean-Claude А что, например, если не картинку ?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный способ пока отсутствует. Существует [connection api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection) но оно пока работает только для некоторых мобильных браузеров.

Так что остаётся грузить любой объёмный объект и считать время загрузки, что вы уже и делаете. Но тут есть проблемы — если используете небольшие объекты, то будет большая погрешность в измерениях, если большие, а у пользователя плохой интернет, вы будете долго ждать результата, а пользователю будет большой трафик. Также можно грузить **много** небольших картинок параллельно подсчитывая среднюю скорость и останавливаясь, когда погрешность измерения будет достаточно небольшой.

Но это всё имеет смысл, если вы именно считаете скорость соединения пользователя. Если вы её измеряете для того, чтобы отдавать ему соответствующий контент (более высокого или низкого качества), лучше мерять его по факту, и переключать по ситуации (у пользователя скорость может изменится в любой момент).

Answer (score 1):

1. Отключить кэширование.
2. Отключить сжатие.

Дальше по схеме из вопроса.

> вы будете долго ждать результата

Сервер может разорвать соединение при необходимости.
Или просто передавать chunked и закончить когда посчитает нужным.